# Odd numbers and 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have two questions:

1. In the script I'm reading right now for discrete mathematics, the definition for an odd number is given by the following equation:

> n is odd <=> ∃ an integer k such that n = 2k + 1

My first question is, can you also define it as:

n is odd <=> ∃ an integer k such that n = **2k - 1**?

<strike>2. One proof for 0 being an even number is that 0 = 2k, where k = 0</strike>

But why couldn't you argue that 0 is odd since 0 = 2k + 1, where k = -1/2 ?

EDIT: Ok, I just realized that -1/2 is not an integer...my bad :)

Comment: Yes, $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z},\text{ such that }n=2k+1$ is equivalent to $\exists K\in\mathbb{Z},\text{ such that }n=2K-1$. You can see that by taking $K=k+1$. With that choice $n=2K-1=2(k+1)-1=2k+2-1=2k+1$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: You could also define odd as not even. Then your definition (in either form) is a theorem. WIth this definition (either form) you need to show that every number is either odd or even but not both (essentially trivial, but logically necessary or asserted as trivially true).